# Cannot connect to a mongoDB atlas database from AWS GLUE to store the result of an ETL process

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

Cannot connect to a mongoDB atlas database from AWS GLUE to store the result of an ETL process.

I have followed the documentation, have tried multiple things with the VPC setup. My VPC has both private and public subnets, public subnets are connected to internet gateway and both subnets are connected to the s3 endpoint - it is pretty much autogenerated by amazon with me only adding s3 endpoint to the public subnet. The connection for aws glue crawler fails for both configs.

To test the connection i have set up a MongoDB atlas crawler. The connection details are correct and mongodb atlas has a 0.0.0.0/0 rule on the network access to allow everything. When i try to run the crawler it fails with this error: "Test connection failed for connection xxxxx". Nothing more is mentioned in logs. The database is accessible from my pc so the access problem must be on the AWS side. My ACL allows for all traffic and the same goes for security rules. I have tried using a NET gateway, however i couldn't access it too. I have tried pinging from my local machine and never received any response.[image: my vpc config]

[image: inbound rules of security group]

[image: outbound rules]

does anybody have any idea what could be the reason behind the lack of connection?